# provisional headers are shown. disable cache to see full headers for google auth login

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-signin

Subdomain working fine with google login but main domain not working, only header error but no error on console log. **I would like to inform that my main domain html php prefix removed but subdomain with php prefix.**

````
    function handleCredentialResponse(response){
      
    // Post JWT token to server-side
    fetch("log", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ request_type:'user_auth', credential: response.credential }),
    });
 
}```
This code with database insert code working working fine with google login in subdomain where is php prefix but my main domain without prefix not working.

I had try below this code:

` <script>
     function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
        decodeJwtResponse(response.credential);
    }

    function parseJwt (token) {
    var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
    var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
    var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(window.atob(base64).split('').map(function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));

    return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
}

function decodeJwtResponse(data){
    console.log(parseJwt(data))
 
}
</script>`

This code working on console log in main domain without prefix and get JSON but its bot working when I create another JS file and put in. Its only working on html body or header.

I want to work on first code which working on subdomain but I want to do without html php prefix. Please help me get out.
````